# How parse JSON formatted rows in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, json

I have a data frame where each row contains JSON formatted input. How can I parse these 3 rows into one table. I tired following commands, but it shows error.

```
a<-data.frame(v1=c('[{"ID":1,"Type":"Honda","Key":{"Service":"Destan","Name":"John"},"Fields":{"Price":23.005,"Cost":10,"DIFF":"13.005"}}]',
                   '[{"ID":2,"Type":"BMW","UpdateType":"Every hour","Key":{"Service":"Destan","Name":"Mark"},"Fields":{"Price":2.005,"Cost":1,"DIFF":"1.005"}}]',
                   '[{"ID":1,"Type":"Honda","Key":{"Service":"Destan","Name":"John"},"Fields":{"Price":13.005,"Cost":4,"DIFF":"9.005"}}]'))
a<-paste0(a$v1, collapse = ",")
l <- fromJSON(paste0(a$v1, collapse = ","))
```

Error is `Error in a$v1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the error message and include which library you are using for the ``fromJSON`` function? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to concat the rows of json into a larger valid json string, I think you'll also need surrounding `[` and `]`. Like:

```
missing_array_ends <- paste0(a$v1, collapse=',')
json_in_r <-  glue::glue("[{missing_array_ends}]") %>% fromJSON
```

But, I think another complication is the nested structure of the json. Key and Field have multiple sub entries. But you can flatten (`unlist`) them if you work on each row (`lapply`). lapply returns a list of items that you want to be rows in a dataframe. `dplyr::bind_rows` combines them back into a single dataframe

```
lapply(a$v1, function(j) unlist(fromJSON(j))) %>%
  bind_rows
```

creates

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  ID    Type  Key.Service Key.Name Fields.Price Fields.Cost Fields.DIFF
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      
1 1     Honda Destan      John     23.005       10          13.005     
2 2     BMW   Destan      Mark     2.005        1           1.005      
3 1     Honda Destan      John     13.005       4           9.005      
# … with 1 more variable: UpdateType <chr>
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, however, imagine that there are 2 sub JSONs inside one big JSON (like the last row value is ```'[{"ID":1,"Type":"Honda","Key":{"Service":"Destan","Name":"John"},"Fields":{"Price":13.005,"Cost":4,"DIFF":"9.005"}},{"ID":3,"Type":"Honda","Key":{"Service":"Destan","Name":"John"},"Fields":{"Price":13.005,"Cost":4,"DIFF":"1.005"}}]'``` How then the last code with bind_rows can work? because if it is added it assumes IDs as different columns

Comment: the data frame doesn't care if you have repeated parts (ID, Type, Service, Name) or even entirly duplicated rows (see `duplicated()` to check). lapply+bind_rows  has given you a "long" format (one identifier in many rows). You can move the data to "wide" using tools like `tidyr::spread` or `tidyr::pivot_wider`. It can get tricky/confusing and might make a good question on it's own.